# Annotated routing in own Symfony3 vendor bundle

Tags: symfony

I want to build a private ecosystem with multiple reusable bundles, similar to the Sonata project. This is my first time so I followed [Symfony2 - creating own vendor bundle - project and git strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523481/symfony2-creating-own-vendor-bundle-project-and-git-strategy) and set up a simple bundle named PUIEconomyBundle with a DefaultController. I imported the bundle into an example project from my Git repo using composer.json.

Now i'm running into a 404 `No route found for "GET /test"`. It's important to have annotated routes to keep an overview. **How do I introduce working annotated routing into my controllers?** The `debug:router` does not mention the route from this bundle, although the profiler says the PUIEconomyBundle is enabled.

#### DefaultController:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/test", name="homepage")
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        dump('Hello!');die;
    }
}
```

#### Extension:

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    //$config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $fileLocator = new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config');
    $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, $fileLocator);
    $loader->load('services.yml');
}
```

#### Services.yml:

```
services:
    pui_economy.routing_loader:
        class: Company\PUI\EconomyBundle\Service\RoutingLoader
        tags:
            - { name: routing.loader }
```

#### RoutingLoader:

```
class RoutingLoader extends Loader
{
    public function load($resource, $type = null)
    {
        $collection = new RouteCollection();

        $resource = '@PUIEconomyBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml';
        $type = 'yaml';

        $importedRoutes = $this->import($resource, $type);

        $collection->addCollection($importedRoutes);

        return $collection;
    }

    public function supports($resource, $type = null)
    {
        return 'advanced_extra' === $type; // ??
    }
}
```

#### Routing.yml:

```
pui_economy:
    resource: "@PUIEconomyBundle/Controller"
        type: annotation
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you forget to add this:

```
app_extra:
    resource: .
    type: extra
```

in `app/config/routing.yml`.

See [Using the custom Loader](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/custom_route_loader.html#using-the-custom-loader).

Comment: I just tried to implement the 'extra' custom loader with the route to `/extra/{parameter}` (also added the method to my DefaultController). Again a 404. I have the idea that the routingloader isn't loaded by the DelegatingLoader, but `php bin/console debug:container` shows my RoutingLoader.. Does Symfony also recognize the `Resources/config/routing.yml` path in every **vendor** bundle or do I need to add something in PUIEconomyBundle.php or PUIEconomyExtension.php?

Comment: Router will load the routes you have registered in your custom loader. You have PUIEconomyBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml (which points to @PUIEconomyBundle/Controller) and you registered it in your custom loader. In indexAction of your DefaultController class, you mention @Route /test, means you can access that action by pointing your browser to something like http://host/test.

Answer (score 0):

Why are u using a custom routing loader? This is a pretty adavanced topic which is not neccessary to simply bind a controller on a route via annotations.

You can find a working example for the @Route annotation here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html

You should also remove the die() statement. Symfony mabey wouldn't give you a response if you kill the request in this way.

Comment: Hi el_wichtel, Im trying to get annotated routes working but it gives a 404 on everything I try. With or without custom routing loaders..

Comment: Can you see the route via the bin/console debug:router command?

Comment: Nope, no routes from my bundle there, but I do see a route from the default AppBundle. The profiler says PUIEconomyBundle is enabled though

Answer (score 0):

**You don't need custom route loader to load your bundle annotated routes.**

I was facing similar issue. All we need is to put this configuration in application where we want to load bundle

> config/routes.yaml

```
my_cool_bundle_routes:
  # loads routes from the given routing file stored in some bundle
  resource: '@XyzAuthBundle/Controller/'
  type:     annotation
```

and that's all :)

`my_cool_bundle_routes` naming is not significant. It just have to be unique.